# 2005 VW Jetta TDI 1.9L Engine Noise

Tags: vw, tdi

I have an engine noise (I'm not quite sure how to explain it- its not a clicking or grinding noise but like a continued rough churning) that occurs when I am traveling in a high gear (5 or 6) at high speeds which just started recently. I know my Dual Mass Flywheel needs replaced because it clicks when I first start it up, but when I am driving it doesn't. The DMF has been clicking ever since I bought it 2 years ago, but never had any other problems with it. I also had the engine fault workshop come up and come off. Does this sound like an additional problem or an extension of the DMF problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry you have not gotten a response to your question. It could be that there isn't enough information for anyone to answer your question. It is near impossible to diagnose a sound over the Internet. This website is geared toward mechanics and DIY enthusiasts who are doing the work and post detailed questions about what they are working on. Without more detail, we may not be able to answer your question. If you are not mechanically inclined, you may need to take this to a mechanic to be diagnosed.